# Hardware Overlay Supported?

Tags: c++, overlay, direct3d9

I'm running on Windows 8 and my VGA is a Geforce 8200m G.
I'm writing a C++ Program and using d3d9 to create a hardware overlay. The question that I want to ask is - does Windows 8 still support hardware overlays and how can I find out if my VGA supports them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Creating a Hardware Overlay Surface
>
> To query for overlay support, call
>   [`IDirect3D9::GetDeviceCaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the driver supports hardware overlay,
>   the `D3DCAPS_OVERLAY` flag is set in the D3DCAPS9.Caps member.